# Primefaces FileUpload doesn't working with Spring

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE, and Primefaces 2.2.1.In my application there is a FileUpload component.However the fileupload is not working.And upload() function in the backingbean FileUploadController is never called.

I include this one to my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my index.xhtml

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="assetUploadDialog" modal="true" minHeight="300"
                  minWidth="550" closable="true" draggable="true"
                  closeOnEscape="true" header="Asset upload">
             <h:form id="formuploader" >
                <p:fileUpload id="fileuploader"
                      fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"
                      sizeLimit="100000"
                      allowTypes="*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.pdf;*.png;*.doc?x;*.xls;*.xlsx;"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

And in my FileUploadController beam class:

```
public class FileUploadController {

    private String destination="D:\\";

     public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
        System.out.println("uplaod");
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        try {
            copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }  
     public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
           try {

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));

                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();

                System.out.println("New file created!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
    }
}
```

What is the solution for my problem?

Comment: My bean class is never invoked.What is the reason for that?

Comment: Primefaces v3.5 released on 4th of Feb http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2436

Comment: Thanks.But I need to complete my work using Primefaces 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form-tag, like in this [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf)